# Increase Rails testing time precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, testing, rspec

We're noticing over time that as our machines get more performant, we end up with more Rails specs with timing issues where it appears that timestamps are not distinct. For example:

```
event1 = create(:event)
event2 = create(:event)
expect(Event.order(:created_at).last).to eq event2
```

The test above has historically been completely reliable, but more recently become flaky apparently due to our computers being more powerful. Sometimes it's `event1`, sometimes it's `event2`. My best guess as to what's happening here is that they end up created so quickly one after another that the timestamps are not distinct. I'm wondering if there is a way to increase the precision of the timestamps in our tests to work around this, or do I just have to manually specify timestamps everywhere? E.g., what we've started doing is something like:

```
event1 = create(:event, created_at: 1.minute.ago)
event2 = create(:event)
expect(Event.order(:created_at).last).to eq event2
```

I'm also wondering if it has anything to do with database timestamp precision, or is it just in Rails land?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue by adding using the [Timecop gem's `scale` tool](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop#timecopscale). It scales time, so 1 second in real time is equivalent, in my case, to 10 seconds in test land. I added the following to my `rails_helper`:

```
config.around do |example|
  Timecop.scale(10) do
    example.run
  end
end
```

After that, all time related specs are passing consistently.

**Update:** this no longer seems to work. Not sure why it worked out for me before, but now I'm getting similar timing errors, despite having `Timecop.scale` around all of my specs.